# Delete first page in JQuery Mobile history

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm doing a Cordova App usin jQuery Mobile. My first page is a 'Loading' page, where I download all needed data for App. After that, App goes to menu. I want to delete that loading page from history.

My problem is that as far as I know, disable insertion of pages inside history can be done only when pages are loaded using $.mobile.changePage (changehash=false).
I'm using jqueryMovile-1.4.2 & cordova 3.4.0.

Does anybody know a approach to this problem?

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using jqueryMovile-1.4.2 & cordova 3.4.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do two things, remove page div from DOM as well as from navigation history. This can be done by listening to `pagecontainershow` and read `ui.prevPage` object, as it holds data of previous page (not current active one).

When `pagecontainershow` fires, check the type of returned `ui.prevPage`, it shouldn't be `undefined`. If it is `defined` (means you have moved from first page in DOM to any other page) at this stage, `.remove()` from DOM and from `$.mobile.navigate.history.stack`.

`$.mobile.navigate.history.stack.splice(0,1);` this will remove first record in urlHistory stack.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function (e, ui) {
  if (typeof ui.prevPage[0] !== "undefined" && ui.prevPage[0].id == "pageID") {
    $.mobile.navigate.history.stack.splice(0,1);
    $(ui.prevPage).remove();
  }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/dHQJ7/)**

Answer (score -1):

What's your issue with changehash=false?

You should just use it when transitionning from the loading page to the menu.

This looks much like what I do in my own app, except in my case history is handled by Backbone.

```
$.mobile.changePage($("#menuPage"), {changeHash: false});
```

And starting with jquery 1.4, you should no more use $.mobile.changePage but instead :

```
$("body").pagecontainer("change",$("#menuPage"), {changeHash: false});
```

Comment: By doing that I'm not adding my menuPage to history. What I want is delete my Waiting/Loading page.