# How set Android's noHistory = "true" feature in Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I developed small app in phonegap. In that after log in success next page is shown by calling

`$.mobile.changePage("secondpage.html");`

It will show some content "secondpage", when i click on back button "login page" is opening. But as per me when i click back button from "secondpage" app should exist. How can i do this..?

In Native android apps we can achieve this by setting noHistrory = "true" in Menifest file with the activity..

Please Help me thanks in advance...

Comment: have you used backbone js?

Comment: No, i'm using cordova-2.7.0.js
jquery-1.9.0.min.js"
jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js" only these js

Comment: $.mobile.urlHistory.clearForward();  try this..

Comment: No its not... Thanks for fair idea

Comment: Check this linkk it worked for me fine...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069421/page-hash-and-backbutton-issue-phonegapjquery